# Faulty auto import with path alias

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, alias, package.json

I'm having strange issue when auto importing services/components from folder provided with path alias within Angular 9 application.

Those are my aliases defined in **tsconfig.json**

```
"paths": {
  "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
  "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"],
  "@state/*": ["app/state/*"]
}
```

Then in Core folder I'm reexporting all services in **index** file (`app/core/index.ts`)

```
export * from './sse/sse.service';
export * from './rack/rack.service';
```

Now when I'm injecting the service in a constructor the provided auto import option gets imported with faulty path:

```
// Incorrect - auto imported path
import { RackService } from '@core/';

// Correct path after manual fix
import { RackService } from '@core/index';
```

It's just a minor issue but quite annoying at the same time and I'm not sure whether it's some incorrect configuration on my side, or VS Code issue. Any idea? Could it be caused by JEST as I'm using it instead of Jasmine and it requires to have aliases defined in `package.json` also.

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/setup-jest.ts"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@core/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1",
      "^@shared/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1",
      "^@state/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/state/$1"
    }
  },
```

Comment: try this out `"@core/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/*",`

Comment: now it fails completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue is caused by the first alias: `@core/*` which can't be then resolved properly in case that the export file is directly on the first level. I came up with two workarounds:

1 - Move the index file to a folder named `services` which contains only the `index.ts`.
Now when auto importing (or TS Hero: Organizes imports) the auto import looks like this:

```
import {someService} from '@core/services'
```

2 - Add path alias to the `tsconfig.*.json` files just for the services pointing directly to re-export `index.ts`

```
"paths": {
  "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
  "@core/services": ["app/core/index.ts"],
  "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"],
  "@state/*": ["app/state/*"]
}
```

Second option also requires changes in `package.json` if you are using Jest framework.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@core/services$": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/index.ts",
  "^@core/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1",      
  "^@shared/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1",
  "^@state/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/state/$1"
}
```

In both cases, if you have any other re-export `index.ts` deeper in the core folder it will still be used correctly, e.g. `@core/commons`