# Angular 10 - baseUrl and paths aren't working

Tags: angular, tsconfig, angular10

I am trying to make relative `import` routes be relative from the `src/` or `app/` folder in a structure like this:

```
+ node_modules
+ src
| + app
| |  + services (just an example)
| |  |  -service.ts
| |  -app.module.ts (etc.)
| - tsconfig.app.json
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to do `import { SomeService } from 'services/some.service'`. However, no matter what I specify in my `tsconfig.json` (or `tsconfig.app.json`), once I do `ng serve`, I receive an error claiming it doesn't know how to import the service.

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  ...
}
```

src/tsconfig.app.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@services/*": [ "app/services/*" ],
      "@interfaces/*": ["app/interfaces/*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

My Angular and Typescript versions:

```
"@angular/core": "^10.2.3",
"typescript": "^3.9.7"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution copied from sandangel's comment from over at [tsconfig paths and module resolution errors in VS Code (GitHub)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8138#issuecomment-345503333) seemed to help:

> vscode seem to only look into nearest tsconfig.json file, while
> angular read your tsconfig.app.json You should add relative path
> config to both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json.

Comment: What does "add relative path config" exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

I thing the **baseUrl** should be like this: `baseUrl: "./"`. Or try setting **baseUrl** to `src`. This is a config from my project:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "src",
  ...
  "paths": {
    "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
    "@core/services": ["app/core/index.ts"],
    "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"],
    "@state/*": ["app/state/*"]
  }
},
```

I'm using index.ts file to reexport all services so they are accessible with `@core/services` path when importing.

I've dealt with similar issue, maybe you can find some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522723/faulty-auto-import-with-path-alias).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work out very well. I have also tried to put everything in `tsconfig.app.json` which extends `tsconfig.json`. Unfortunately, that (updated the code above) didn't work either.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. Just out of curiosity, have you tried removing/reverting the changes in `tsconfig.app.json`? I've seen multiple instructions how to set up path aliases and I never seen changes in that file.

Comment: I have done some more *ahem* "research" and it turns out sandangel's comment from [tsconfig paths and module resolution errors in VS Code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8138) (GitHub) seemed to help.